# Which ubuntu to install on 32 bit machine having 4 gb ram

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a 32 bit machine and had planned to install ubuntu 14.04 on it. I am confused because on the ubuntu download page it says 32 bit (for machines less than 2 gb ram) , since I have 4 gb of ram on my machine should i go ahead with installating the 64 bit . Also what about the other applications should i need to install 32 bit or 64 bit version of the app ?

Comment: you can't install software that is meant to work on 64bit architecture on 32bit architecture.

Comment: I've never heard of a 32 bit machine having 8GB of RAM because the limit for a 32 bit machine is 4GB, simply put that machine has to be a 64 bit one with 32 bit windows or something on it. I would suggest to try to install the 64 bit one on it. If the 64 bit boots then that machine is actually 64 bit.

Comment: oops my bad, I actually have a 64 bit machine . I ll just modify the question to suit other people in such problem.